# Не получается разобраться с паттерном registry

Tags: php

Не получается разобраться с паттерном registry.

Хочу понять его работу на примере взятом из видео-урока:

```
<?php
$conf = array (
'parts' => array(
    'contr' => 'app/Controller',
    'mod' => 'app/model/mod_main.php'
),
'что - то др.' => array(
    '' => '',
    '' => '',
    '' => ''
)
);


class Registry {
   public static $obj = array();

   protected static $instance;

   protected function __construct() {
        global $conf;
        foreach ($conf['parts'] as $name => $parts) {
            self::$obj[$name] = new $parts;
        }
   }

   public static function instance () {
        if(self::$instance === null) self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
   }

   public function __set($name, $obj) {
        if (!isset(self::$obj[$name])) self::$obj[$name] = new $obj;
   }

   public function __get($name) {
        if (is_object(self::$obj($name))) return self::$obj($name);
   }
}
?>
```

Когда я делаю все это в индексном файле, тогда все срабатывает. Но я не понимаю, как работать с контроллерами, дополнительными классами (библиотеками) и регистром. Потому что если я создаю объект регистра в индексном файле в корне и записываю, например, библиотеку в регистр и потом пытаюсь вызвать ее через этот самый регистр, то ничего не получается.

Объясните пожалуйста простым языком, как использовать регистр так, чтобы все добавленные библиотеки я мог бы использовать в любой части кода.

Comment: Видимо вам нужна автозагрузка классов http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: и все?? это все решает?

Comment: @privetsh - а что значит "ничего не получается"? наверное же вам ошибки валит, думаю в них написаны причины самой ошибки. И если не получается не в текущем коде, то создайте пример где не получается.